# Do SQLite3 commands work when inside of functions in Python?

Tags: python, sqlite

So I'm trying to make a login system using SQLite3 to store the user info, to create the table I made the following functions.

```
def create_sql_table():
    cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(userName TEXT, passWord TEXT, score INTEGER)''')
    conn.commit()
    return conn
```

The code runs without errors but in PyCharm, I don't see any tables in the database view. Does anyone know where I went wrong? The full code is available here: https://github.com/VladRadoi08/Snake-LoginUI

Comment: How did you confirm that the table wasn't created? The sql file would be a binary dump. What do you see if you run the following after the create_table_function()?

`cursor.execute('select * from users').fetchall()`

Comment: PyCharm has a "Database" view tool, so I went to that, apparently, if a table is created inside the database, it should show there. I'm assuming the table was made since the code ran without errors. @fibonachoceres

Comment: If you execute the line of code in my previous comment and it runs without error, that means that the table is created and this issue is related to PyCharm's SQL Viewer and not the python driver.

Comment: and i think `conn.commit()` is not required here, i think its used just for `DML` statements

Comment: @fibonachoceres hey! i added the line of code you mentioned and ran the code and i didn't get any errors. so i think you're right! thanks for the help.